# Function goes out of scope for first time

Tags: swift, parsing, graphql, apollo

I'm new to SwiftUI, I'm facing challenge in parsing the below code

```
func fetchFullAccountNumber(accNumberID: String) {
    Network.shared.apiGetAccountNumber(accountNumberID: accNumberID) { accNumber in
        self.fullNumber = accNumber  
    } onFailure: { error in
        //
        print(error.debugDescription)
    }        
}
```

The above request is from Apollo GraphQL,
My Problem is, on running above code, on first time the control goes out of scope, i.e., `self.fullNumber` is not parsed, and on second time onwards it works fine.
How shall I resolve this issue, and make it run on first time only?

I tried checking for `accNumber` is nil compared that, but it didn't solve it.

Comment: It’s not easy to understand your English but I assume the problem you have is that you make an asynchronous call and then tries to access the property `fullNumber` before the answer has arrived.

Comment: why is fullNumber not assigned with value, I'm assigning after it's operation

Comment: You need to understand what _asynchronous programming_ means. It is assigned a value but not directly.

Comment: Do `func fetchFullAccountNumber(accNumberID: String) { print("Will call Get Account Number API"); Network.shared.apiGetAccountNumber(accountNumberID: accNumberID) { accNumber in print("Did Get Account Number API"); self.fullNumber = accNumber } onFailure: { error in print(error.debugDescription) }; print("End of the Get Account Number API method") }`, see the prints in console, and compare with the order you thought it should be in console. That should illustrate the asynchronous concept.

Comment: I tried adding breakpoint to check the flow